# Execution of a python script from ubuntu shell

Tags: python, ubuntu

I wrote a python script I want to call from an ubuntu shell. One of the arguments of my function is a list of tuples. However, when I write this list of tuples, the following error is raised:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('

How can I ignore the '('?

Invocation:

```
python scriptName.py [(1,2,3), (4,3,5), (3,4,5)]
```

Comment: please post full invocation (what you type in bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell does not like your list of arguments, because it contains characters which have special meaning to the shell.

You can get around that with quoting or escaping;

```
python scriptName.py '[(1,2,3), (4,3,5), (3,4,5)]'
```

or if your script really wants three separate arguments and glues them together by itself

```
python scriptName.py '[(1,2,3),' '(4,3,5),' '(3,4,5)]'
```

Better yet, change your script so it can read an input format which is less challenging for the shell.  For large and/or complex data sets, the script should probably read standard input (or a file) instead of command-line arguments.

(Parentheses start a subshell and are also used e.g. in the syntax of the `case` statement.  Square brackets are used for wildcards.)

Comment: Problem is: In my code, I called every tuple in the list in a for loop (for t in argv[1] etc). However, when I do a for t in argv[1], the script doesn't understand I have a list and t is [ then ( etc. Is there a way to make it understand I have tuples?

Comment: `eval` and in Python 2 `input` do this sort of parsing.  Using Python's internal representation for your data may not be ideal, though.  Perhaps it would make sense to use e.g. JSON for input?

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your argument, so it will be treated as single string. Then you can access it from sys.argvs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ast

try:
    literal = sys.argv[1]
except KeyError:
    print "nothing to parse"
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    obj = ast.literal_eval(literal)
except SyntaxError:
    print "Could not parse '{}'".format(literal)
    sys.exit(2)

print repr(obj)
print type(obj)
```

Then in bash:

```
$ python literal.py "[(1,2,3), (4,3,5), (3,4,5)]"
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 3, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
<type 'list'>
```

For more about command line syntax in bash, see:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Syntax